# How to fetch profile pic with facebooker2 other than current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebooker2

How do I fetch the profile pics of users who have granted my application permission for offline access?

Example:
User 1 grants my application permissions and log in.

User 2 logs in, and is able to see the profile pic of User 1, without having any fb connections to User 1.

How do I display the profile pic of User 1 to User 2 with facebooker2?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= fb_profile_pic(**User 1 facebook ID**, :facebook_logo => false, :linked => true, :size => "normal") %>
```

You can set the size of the picture and other options by checking out this page: http://facebooker.pjkh.com/helpers/fb_profile_pic

Cheers!

`</Westy92>`